# Convert WordPress to Jekyll has a error of Ruby MySQL

Tags: ruby, wordpress, jekyll

```
➜ henryyan@hy-hp  ~/work/blog/henryyan.github.com git:(master) ✗ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll/migrators/wordpress"; Jekyll::WordPress.process("wordpress", "root", "root")'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': LoadError: no such file to load -- mysql (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:312:in `block in tsk_require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:94:in `block in check_requiring_thread'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:91:in `check_requiring_thread'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:312:in `tsk_require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25:in `adapter_class'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:63:in `connect'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:141:in `connect'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:345:in `adapter_method'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.33.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:352:in `mysql'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/wordpress.rb:15:in `process'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the mysql gem:

```
gem install mysql
```

See the same error on this other SO answer: [Wordpress to Jekyll script throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687350/wordpress-to-jekyll-script-throwing-error)

Comment: before 
`gem install mysql`
please install **libmysqlclient15-dev**